Activate button in DownloadString
By creating the webBrowser on the Form, I can activate the button via code and read new information. But trying to retrieve the information via DownloadString(url) which also works.
    string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser()
    {
       ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
       DocumentText = string.Empty
    };
    System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document.OpenNew(true);
    doc.Write(html);
    doc.InvokeScript("Submit");

The page has functions where each button refreshes with new information and the URL does not change. The first time I go to the page, the button looks like this
`
<button class="btn btn-result btn-primary" id="btn-tekinfo" data-page="page-tekinfo" data-name="tekinfo" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; gtag('event', 'Resultat Buttons', {'Click': 'Tek'});"><span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light" role="status" style="display: none;"><span class="sr-only">...</span></span> Tek</button>
`

and the content that I look at looks like this.
`<tr>
<td class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Brand</td>
<td id="brand">Visual Studio</td>
</tr>`

when the button has been pressed and the page updated, it looks like this.
`<tr id="placeholder-tek_total" class="hide" style="display: table-row;">
<td class="text-uppercase" width="60%">Tek Total</td>
<td width="40%"><span id="tek_total">2019</span> v</td>
</tr>`

But how can I activate the button and fetch new information without using webBrowser physically?
`Another question. When using webBrowser on Form, errors appear with reference to this script: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js
Is it normal? And can I use it?`
As a beginner, there is always a lot of trying and searching, but everything is a learning process that only gives new areas to try. Have become "smarter", but still a lot to learn, such as the terms to be able to search. Haven't got that experience and knowledge yet, so I hope you can help me.

Does this answer your question? C# Click HTML Button from Webclient

Shut down for today, but hopefully I can look at it tomorrow. Previously saw this https://youtu.be/NvT5QRTpys4?si=jYQ5qIuEo6l23b_7 which sounds a bit the same. Should work if I can figure it out. Thanks you.

Headers from youtube, I don't think I can use, based on my little knowledge. And it seems that there was information shown in the post you referred to that is no longer on the page, so don't know what the information refers to :( (/View/DashboardProxy.php?location=Dashboard/RequestServlet&postdata=1)

I referred to this answer which says that's not possible
